# Select record in Access with most recent date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access  table.

```
ID  Field1  Field2  Date
1   un_1    x       201701
2   un_2    y       201704
3   un_1    z       201702
4   un_3    a       201703
5   un_2    b       201709
```

I would like to take the unique (for Field1) records of this table where Date is the most recent.

I tried:

```
SELECT ID, Field1, Field2, Date
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE Date=SELECT(MAX(MYTABLE.Date) FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID=MYTABLE.ID)
GROUP BY Field1;
```

But it is not working.

As result I would expect:

```
un_1    z       201702
un_2    b       201709
un_3    a       201703
```

Comment: With that sample data, what is the expected result?

Comment: Skip the GROUP BY. Enclose the sub-query with parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. You need to put the parentheses around the subquery, like this, and you need to add a synonym for your table, because you're using the same table twice:

```
SELECT ID, Field1, Field2, Date
FROM MYTABLE i
WHERE MYTABLE.[Date]=(SELECT MAX(t.[Date]) FROM MYTABLE t WHERE t.ID=i.ID)
ORDER BY Field1;
```

Comment: Thanks. It gives back Synthax Error in `Date=(SELECT MAX(t.Date) FROM MYTABLE t WHERE t.ID=MYTABLE.ID)` (P.S. `t` is not defined, is it?)

Comment: `t` is defined as an alias of `MYTABLE` here: `FROM MYTABLE t`. You can change it to `FROM MYTABLE As t` if you want your SQL to be more explicit, but that's just extra text. Review the current edit, `Date` is a keyword and should not be used for field names

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work. Maybe I was not clear enough in the question I have added the expected result. Sorry about that.

Comment: It gives syntax error. My query with the proper names is: `SELECT PARTNERID, NAME, FIRST_NAME, CF, DATA_R

FROM MYTABLE

WHERE MYTABLE.[DATA_R]=
(
SELECT MAX(t.[DATA_R]) 
FROM MYTABLE as t 
WHERE t.PARTNERID=MYTABLE.PARTNERID
)
ORDER BY PARTNERID
;`
The error is in the SELECT MAX part as reported by Access.

Comment: Try to add `[ ]` square brackets around `NAME`, and add a synonym for `MyTable` in the outer query too.