# Access: query crashes

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query (let's call it Query1) (kindly created [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46581638/select-record-in-access-with-most-recent-date/46581690#46581690) by [Erik von Asmuth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-von-asmuth)):

```
SELECT PARTNERID
    ,NAME
    ,FIRST_NAME
    ,UID
    ,DATA_R
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE MY_TABLE.[DATA_R] = (
        SELECT MAX(t.[DATA_R])
        FROM MY_TABLE AS t
        WHERE t.PARTNERID = MY_TABLE.PARTNERID
        )
ORDER BY PARTNERID;
```

`MY_TABLE` has `20000` records and is a Query (even if the name might suggest the opposite) with the following form:

```
SELECT [MYTABLE_O].PARTNERID, [MYTABLE_O].NAME, [MYTABLE_O].FIRST_NAME, [MYTABLE_O].[Codice fiscale] AS CF, [MYTABLE_O].Date AS DATA_R
FROM [MYTABLE_O] LEFT JOIN [TO_EXCLUDE] ON [MYTABLE_O].[PARTNERID] = [TO_EXCLUDE].[PARTNERID]
WHERE ((([TO_EXCLUDE].PARTNERID) Is Null));
```

(I want to exclude some already considered elements that are in Table `TO_EXCLUDE`).

When I run the query (Query1) MS Access freezes. How can I avoid it/make it more efficient and stable?

I have tried to index in `MYTABLE_O` both `PARTNERID` AND `DATA_R`

Comment: Apply an index on [DATA_R].

Comment: Could you further explain this? Maybe with an example?

Comment: I really don't like receiving feedback on my answers in a new question. Just comment on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46581638/select-record-in-access-with-most-recent-date/46581690#46581690)

Comment: You are right but the problem is that it is my collegue's account and I do not have his password

Comment: @cacc: i think we are not living in the stone age :-) If the case is what you are describing(i.e that the previous account belong to your colleague and there is no way for you to get password) then you need to mention in the question about the previous post, the original problem, Erik 's answer and any update and so on... Also kindly read what to do when [some one answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you question

Comment: I have updated my question. I do not have his password and I guess he'll accept the question when he'll come back to work next week.

Comment: As for indexes, you can read in on how to create them [on this office support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-0a8e2aa6-735c-4c3a-9dda-38c6c4f1a0ce). The most important thing is that `PARTNERID` should be indexed, and as @Gustav stated, `DATA_R` should be indexed too

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. `MY TABLE` is actually a query that reads from `MY_OTHER_TABLE` where I have indexed both `PARTNERID` and `DATA_R`. Still the query is very slow and when I scroll down it freezes

Comment: If you're looking to optimize your code, skipping over that query and reading directly from the table is probably the way to do it. However, you haven't provided the query, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: Is now more clear?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to write the result of the subquery:

```
SELECT PARTNERID, MAX([DATA_R]) AS MAXDATAR
FROM YourQuery
GROUP BY PARTNERID
```

to a temp table, and then replace in your query

```
FROM MY_TABLE AS t
```

with

```
FROM TempTable AS t
```

Comment: Thanks. But then how should I edit the part of `DATA_R` in the initial query? If I do like this `WHERE MY_TABLE.[DATA_R] = (
        SELECT MAX(t.[MAXDATAR])
        FROM TempTabe AS t
        WHERE t.PARTNERID = MY_TABLE.PARTNERID
        )
` I only have as date result the max date in the sample that is not what I need since I would like the records associated with the max date for the specific `PARTNERID` (so the relative MAX DATE and not the absolute). Or maybe I have not understood the entire picture. STEP1) is MyOriginal Table, STEP2) is TempTable and STEP3) Is the initial query?

Comment: You could create a copy of your initial query and modify it to create the temp table.